# Which part of the car will be damaged in this case?

Tags: toyota, handbrake

I have a Toyota Etios Liva Viera Limited Edition car, which is going to be 3 years old next January.

The greatest problem that we face is that, no one in our family knows how to drive. As a result, we have to depend on drivers, and in many cases, their driving skills are not up to the mark.

Last day, the driver kept on pressing the accelerator even though the hand brake was set. There is a sign for the hand brake in the car panel, but he didn't know what that meant. So, even after explaining it to him, he kept on pressing the accelerator when the hand brake was set.

Now once something was done, I couldn't reverse it. I want to know which part of the car would be damaged in this case. I have a yearly servicing scheduled in January, and I can ask the service personnel to check that part once. Is it the clutch that'll be affected? Or any other part?

I live in Kolkata, India.

Comment: Was the car moving? If so then check the handbrake. Was he slipping the clutch - did it start to smell? If so you may need to get that checked but once can be ok.

Comment: No, the car wasn't moving, but a noise was coming, which showed that the engine was trying to accelerate but couldn't move due to the hand brake. No smell. I don't know whether he had pressed the clutch pedal during this. He was actually trying to drive in normal manner with hand brake set in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are no damage was done, manufactures build in a certain amount of tolerance for driver abuse for such reasons.

As the car wasn't moving it suggests that there would be no wear on the friction surface of the brake pads/shoes, if the handbrake still works as it should then that suggests no linkage or other parts where damage and finally as the was no obvious signs of smell or bad clutch slip the clutch is almost certainly fine to.

With only one or two occurrences of this happening I would say almost certainly there is no damage caused. I would say that unless there is any symptoms do not mention the situation to your mechanics at the next service unless you know they are 100% legit and honest as they could use this to their advantage and charge you for unneeded work.

Comment: I can assure you that the mechanics are 100% legit. It's the Toyota authorised service centre.

Comment: Ha ! some people believe anything...